# Why this error in discord.py api wish logging user?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
import asyncio

 # Retrieved from browser local storage

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(client.servers)


client.login('email', 'password')
```

** Error: TypeError: login() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given. I was given 2 arguments, but error..**

Comment: You need to login with your bot token, not email/password. Self bots are against discord ToS and not supported by discord.py.

Comment: @moinierer3000 and in the same place if a personal account, then the bot token violates some rules? perhaps there is some other api?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to the discord.py documentation, the Client.login() function takes only one argument, and that is the bot's token (it used to take two, but the `bot` argument has been deprecated since version 1.7). [Here's the reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.login).

So the correct version of your code would be:

```
import discord
import asyncio

 # Retrieved from browser local storage

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(client.servers)


client.login('your-bot-token')
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Your info on the development is outdated, discord.py resumed development a couple of weeks ago: https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/c4324f17a80c94776832430007ad40e6

Comment: Oh, my bad! I'll make the changes in my answer.